# Do I need to install MAAS in order to install OpenStack on a single server?

Tags: maas, openstack, cloud

I am installing ubuntu openstack on a single server, to test a learn about it.

Do I need to install MAAS if I just have a single server? What else do I need to know about this installation?

I am following this guide: [install ubuntu openstack](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide you are referring to is for setting up a production or PoC instance. MAAS is only needed if you are going to provision multiple physical servers.

For a single-node scenario, check out Adam's guide at http://astokes.org/ubuntu-openstack-installer/ for a very simple walkthrough of the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Updated link - old one points to a document which no longer exists: http://astokes.org/start